# How to i get a specific value from a json encoded array?

Tags: javascript, php, json

Here is my JavaScript and my PHP for a dynamic ajax search. I am trying to get data from the database and display it in my DOM as a string.

javascript

```
var searchBox = document.getElementById("searchBox");
var searchButton = document.getElementById("searchButton");
var search = getXmlHttpRequestObject();

searchBox.addEventListener("keyup", ajaxSearch);

function getXmlHttpRequestObject(){
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else if (window.ActiveXObject){
    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  else{
    alert("Your browser does not support our dynamic search");
  }
}

function ajaxSearch(){
  var str = escape(document.getElementById('searchBox').value);
  search.open("GET", '../searchSuggest.php?search=' + str, true);
  search.send(null);
  delay(displaySuggestions);
}

function displaySuggestions(){
  var ss = document.getElementById("searchSuggestion");
  ss.innerHTML = '';
  string = search.responseText;
  ss.innerHTML = string;
}


function delay(functionName){
setTimeout(functionName, 100);
}

function setSearch(x){
  document.getElementById("searchBox").value = x;
  document.getElementById("searchSuggestion").innerHTML = "";
}

searchBox.addEventListener('click', ajaxSearch);
window.addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.getElementById('searchSuggestion').innerHTML = '';
  });
```

php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "Products";

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $searchValue = $_GET['search'];

  if(isset($searchValue) && $searchValue != ''){
    $search = addslashes($searchValue);
    $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT Name FROM Product WHERE Name LIKE('%" . $search . "%') ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN Name like '" . $search . " %' THEN 0
    WHEN Name like '" . $search . "%' THEN 1
    WHEN Name like '% " . $search . "%' THEN 2
    ELSE 3
    END, Name");
    $statement->execute();


    $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $json = json_encode($result);
    echo $json;

  }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
?>
```

What i want to know i how to get specific values from my response.

```
[{"Name":"iMac"},{"Name":"iPad 2"},{"Name":"iPhone 5"},{"Name":"iPhone 6"},{"Name":"iPod Touch"},{"Name":"iWatch"}]
```

For my search to work effectively i need it to display just the string of the product name and not the whole object.

Comment: you don't extract from a json string. You decode the string to a native structure (e.g. `JSON.parse` it), then it's just a plain javascript array/object and you access whatever you want like you would in any other array/object.

Comment: That code is ***BAD BAD BAD***, you should ***NOT*** be using a timeout to wait for an Ajax request to come back. It has built in mechanisms to do that!

Comment: what does `display it in my DOM as a string` mean? Surely you want to generate html for it which is relatively simple by looping over the array from response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a delay rather than the ajax callback is just shockingly prone to failure. Suppose your ajax call takes more than 100ms? It can totally happen. Similarly, why wait 100ms if your server is nice and fast and it finishes in 25?

Ditch the global `search` object, and change this:

```
function ajaxSearch(){
  var str = escape(document.getElementById('searchBox').value);
  search.open("GET", '../searchSuggest.php?search=' + str, true);
  search.send(null);
  delay(displaySuggestions);
}
```

to

```
function ajaxSearch(){
  var str = escape(document.getElementById('searchBox').value);
  var search = getXmlHttpRequestObject();
  if (search) {
    search.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (search.readyState == 4 && search.status == 200) {
            displaySuggestions(JSON.parse(search.responseText));
        }
    };
    search.open("GET", '../searchSuggest.php?search=' + str, true);
    search.send(null);
  }
}
```

Then `displaySuggestions` receives an array:

```
function displaySuggestions(results) {
  // Use standard array techniques on `results`, e.g., `results[0]` is the first,
  // maybe loop while `index < results.length`, maybe use `results.forEach(...)`...
}
```

---

Or taking it further, let's add a level of convenience there:

```
var failed = false;
function getXmlHttpRequestObject(done, failed){
  var xhr;

  if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else if (window.ActiveXObject){
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  else {
    if (!failed) {
      alert("Your browser does not support our dynamic search");
      failed = true;
    }
    return null;
  }

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      if (xhr.status == 200 {
        if (done) {
          done(xhr);
        }
      } else {
        if (failed) {
          failed(xhr);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  return xhr;
}
```

Then:

```
function ajaxSearch(){
  var str = escape(document.getElementById('searchBox').value);
  var search = getXmlHttpRequestObject(function(xhr) {
    displaySuggestions(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
  });
  if (search) {
    search.open("GET", '../searchSuggest.php?search=' + str, true);
    search.send(null);
  }
}
```